# Valid Properties for CheckBox.Name

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on a task that has me populating a window (dynamically) with options for the users to select.  I'm trying to name the `Checkbox`'s and I get an error at runtime when I'm testing:

```
'cbPS_Steel, Carbon - Schedule 40' is not a valid value for property 'Name'.
```

The `Name` Property takes a `string` value, but it's not taking the values I pass to the property, even though they are strings.  Could this be because of the hyphen or the spaces?

### Specifically:

Are there any characters that the `Name` property for `Checkbox`'s deemed as invalid?  Any information, or articles would be helpful.  Thank you!

### Code:

```
cb.Name = setCheckBoxName(cb, 2);

private string setCheckBoxName(CheckBox cb, int iCase)
{
    string name = "";

    switch (iCase)
    {
       case 0:
           name = "cbAS_" + cb.Content.ToString();
           break;
       case 1:
           name = "cbRV_" + cb.Content.ToString();
           break;
       case 2:
           name = "cbPS_" + cb.Content.ToString();
           break;
       case 3:
           name = "cbMS_" + cb.Content.ToString();
           break;
       default: break;
    }

    return name;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Name` property allows you to reference the control from code behind (when used in `Xaml` for example) so it has to be valid with the same restrictions as variable names

And a variable name cannot contain hyphen nor spaces :)

**EDIT:** Look at the comments, there are less restrictions in the `Name` property. Thanks **@O.R.Mapper**

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Yitschak.  I figured that's what it was.  A lot of my `Checkbox`'s would have names like this.  I was trying to set them up like this so I can compare things at a later time, but I suppose comparing the `.Content` will be just as effective.

Comment: @GeoffOverfield maybe the Tag property may be useful instead of subclassing :)

Comment: Well, actually, [you can use some control characters that look like spaces in identifiers](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/02/17/spaces-in-identifier-names-in-c/).

Comment: "it has to be valid with the same restrictions as variable names" - that does not seem to be correct. Variable names must not match C# keywords, but the `Name` property can be set to a string matching a C# keyword. At least, unless you count the `@` that you can then use to refer to the variable again as a part of the variable name.

Answer (score 3):

This is described in the [documentation on the `FrameworkElement.Name` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.name(v=vs.110).aspx). It says:

> The string values used for Name have some restrictions, as imposed by the underlying x:Name Directive defined by the XAML specification. Most notably, a Name must start with a letter or the underscore character (_), and must contain only letters, digits, or underscores. For more information, see WPF XAML Namescopes.

With that said, it would probably be a cleaner solution to subclass `Checkbox` and add a property that helps you tell your checkboxes apart to that subclass.

Comment: Great Idea!  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @GeoffOverfield maybe the Tag property may be useful instead of subclassing :)